# hiding training progress bar with chatterbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

I'm training my chatbot using chatterbot and I downloaded and parsed a dataset for training, but I'm running into issues because I have 83000 samples, but the trainer insists on displaying a progress bar every iteration whereas I'd like to use a single one to show the progress bar for all of the conversations.

Is there a way to hide the training progress bar in chatterbot?

I saw a post on here about setting the logging level, but I haven't managed to get that to work for me, is that the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You might rewrite method train in class ListTrainer.

```
class ListTrainer(Trainer):
"""
Allows a chat bot to be trained using a list of strings
where the list represents a conversation.
"""

def train(self, conversation):
    """
    Train the chat bot based on the provided list of
    statements that represents a single conversation.
    """
    previous_statement_text = None
    previous_statement_search_text = ''

    statements_to_create = []

    for conversation_count, text in enumerate(conversation):
        if self.show_training_progress:
            pass
```